# Are Android programming questions for this site or Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

[Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) already has lots of questions regarding Android programming. Should this site try to stick to questions about using/owning an Android device, rather than developing for it? Or is the idea to include anything about Android devices?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

My two cents:

If the question is programming related, SO makes the most sense to me.  This may be a fair place for input regarding user interface questions during app development, though, so long as you can keep the question from being overly subjective.  This is a site for Android users (and power users), not necessarily programmers.

Answer (score 12):

Programming questions should remain on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 2):

If the question is somewhat related to programming, such as building, developing, and debugging Android Apps, you should use Stack Overflow.

However, when the question is related to the Android Device, such as Hardware-related or software-related issues, using adb, and others, then you should post / ask the question on Android Enthusiasts.

Comment: I don't see that this adds anything not already covered in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Unless/until [the Android Developers suggestion at Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7418/android-developers) takes off, I think SO should be used for development questions.

Comment: It's been closed, so that answers that.  Too bad in my opinion.