# Should there be an Amazon Fire tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is the tag [amazon-kindle-fire](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kindle-fire), which has the synonym [kindle-fire](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindle-fire). While early Fire tablets were branded as Kindle Fire, [current models](https://www.amazon.com/b/?ie=UTF8&node=6669703011&ref_=fs_ods_fs_tab_cp), such as [the Fire HD 8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0794RHPZD), do not have "Kindle" as part of their name.

Should the tag [amazon-fire](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-fire) be added? (I have a question about developing for Fire tablets. Update: I now know not to ask development questions.)

Comment: Umm, have you checked out our [help/on-topic]? Development questions are off-topic here. :-)

Comment: @Firelord Whoops, although the tag suggestion still stands.

Comment: Android-fire/Amazon-fire I am confused.

Comment: Oops, I meant Amazon fire. I'll fix the title.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is reasonable.

Before this question was posted, there are already [amazon-fire-phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-fire-phone) and [amazon-fire-tv](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-fire-tv).

Based on a quick search, looks like some questions were mistagged with its Kindle Fire version, thus I decided to fix some of them and added:

- [amazon-fire](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-fire) (not sure about this, probably for general Amazon Fire devices, to be discussed more)
- [amazon-fire-5th-gen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-fire-5th-gen)
- [amazon-fire-7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-fire-7)
- [amazon-fire-hd-8](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-fire-hd-8)
- [amazon-fire-hd-10](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-fire-hd-10)

---

<sup>That said, development-related questions are off-topic as per [Are Android programming questions for this site or Stack Overflow?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6/44325)</sup>